# "Угадай число" на С++

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Нужно написать игру "Угадай число". Вводишь число и количество попыток. Ввел число (его не выводить), а тот, кто угадывает, получает количество попыток. И там по ходу пишет сколько попыток осталось.

Подскажите, как сделать, дайте отправную точку, код не нужен - просто мысль.

Сделал примерно так:

```
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
    int a, b, p;
    std::cout << "Vvedite chislo" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo popitok" << std::endl;
    std::cin>>p;

    int s = 0, e = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {       
        std::cin>>b;
        if(b > a)
            std::cout << "Bolshe" << std::endl; //Подсказка 1
        else if(b < a)
            cout<<"Menshee"<<endl; // Подсказка 2
        else if(b == a)
        {
            std::cout << "Vi ugadali chislo" << std::endl;
            break; // Завершает цикл  
        }

        s += e;
    }

    std::cout << "Popitka nomer - " << s << std::endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
int number=(число, которое надо угадать);
int N=(количество попыток);
while(N)
{
    cout << "Попыток осталось: " << N << endl;
    int value;
    cin >> value;
    if(value==number)
    {
        cout << "Число угадано!\n";
        break;
    }
    N--;
}
```

Это псевдокод, так как на самом деле русский текст некорректно выводится.

Comment: Надо поробовать и так тоже)

Answer (score 1):

Лобовым циклом по количеству попыток: на каждой итерации выводите (количество попыток минус номер итерации) и запрашиваете число, если число то что нужно - обрабатываете и вываливаетесь из цикла. Вроде все :)

Comment: а как нить проще без массивов.Это по идее учебное задание ,которое дали без объяснений...

Comment: а я ничего про массивы не говорил

Comment: Прочитав "итераций" подумал про массивы ,простите.

Answer (score 1):

Спросить больше, меньше или равно загаданное число данному.

Далее применить двоичный поиск. Начальный диапазон MIN_INT : MAX_INT.

Первая попытка отгадать - 0.

Comment: Я только начал С++ изучать,надо будет прочитать про MIN_INT:MAX_INT

Comment: Да, и заодно про двоичный поиск (или это знаете ?) Кстати, прошу прощения, ошибся. Не MIN_INT, MAX_INT, а **INT_MAX и INT_MIN**. 

Они определены в  <limits.h>

Comment: О нее для меня это ново,с удовольствием почитаю )
Нашел проще способ решения,откровенно сделанный на "отстань" из за сроков )

Comment: Подскажите как сделать чтобы при вводе с клавиатуры число не показывалось? )

Comment: В \*nix проще всего (для тестов и т.п.) system("stty -echo"); 

Только потом не забудьте опять включить отображение ввода system("stty echo");

В винде не помню (поищите сами).